# Force instance methods to use only public members

Tags: c#

What do you think about code like this:

```
public class ThisClass
{
    // this method uses only public members
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        AccessToPublicMembersOfThisClass.DoSomething(this);
    }
}

// EDIT: this class is not nested!
internal class AccessToPublicMembersOfThisClass
{
    internal void static DoSomething (ThisClass x)
    {
       // we are sure were using only public members because
       // private members are unaccessible from here

        x.Action();
    }
}
```

Is it good or not?

I could do some static methods, but I don't want to pass any arguments to them.

Comment: By default, a method has access to data declared within it. Such data need not be static. Such data need not be passed as arguments. No need to pass 'this' or create static methods within a non-static class.

Comment: Can't the user of ThisClass just call Action() directly? What does any of this code allow you to do that you couldn't do before?

Comment: When I'm in AccessToPublicMembersOfThisClass I cannot use private members of ThisClass. And I'm sure methods like that are easy to refactor etc. But maybe extensions methods are better? Or both solutions sucks and I should stay with normal methods :)

Comment: You can't access private members of ThisClass from DoSomething because DoSomething is static (not sure why you do this), it can't depend on an instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it good or not?

It is decidedly not good.

If you don't want some function to access private methods, then that is an overwhelming sign that it shouldn't be a part of the class.

Worse, it's not clear that you are trying to enforce that, meaning the next programmer that comes along is likely to just undo this and work with the private variables directly. If you want a function kinda-sorta on the class, but needs to live elsewhere, use extension methods - that's why they're there.